# How can i clear the selection made on a Richfaces extendedDataTable when i change the current page using a dataScroller

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a extendedDataTable on wich you can select a row and then several commandButton will become enabled to perform operations on that item.

What I need to do is to clear the selection and disable the buttons once the user changes the current page using a dataScroller.

I'm using JSF with Richfaces 4.3

Comment: If you use RichFaces 4.3 then tag jsf-1.2 is wrong. Proper tag: jsf-2 or jsf-2.2.

Comment: Thanks i edited it